# postgresql insert dynamic query result into table in cursor

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i have the following function, that generates dynamic query and at the end i want to insert result of dynamic query into table, but the error i get is `

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function report_get_result(integer) line 46 at SQL statement
> SQL statement "SELECT report_get_result(20150131)"
> PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at PERFORM
> ********** Error **********'
> ```

body of the function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report_get_result (
datekey integer
) returns setof logic_result_rcd
AS
$body$
DECLARE
    LogicID integer;
    SheetName text;
    Row_ID text;
    Column_ID text;
    FromTable text;
    Operation text;
    Amount text;
    CriteriaType_1 text;
    Function_1 text;
    Criteria_1 text;
    CriteriaType_2 text;
    Function_2 text;
    Criteria_2 text;
    CriteriaType_3 text;
    Function_3 text;
    Criteria_3 text;
    sql text;
    INC Integer;
begin
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS loans;
 create temp table loans as
 select * from loan.vfact_state_principal where "DateKey" = datekey;

 DECLARE cursor_logic REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
 OPEN cursor_logic for execute ('SELECT "LogicID" FROM logic_table_rcd');
 LOOP
    FETCH cursor_logic INTO INC;
    if not found then exit;
    end if;
    BEGIN
 SELECT  LogicID = "LogicID"
            ,SheetName = "SheetName"
            ,Row_ID = "Row_ID"::text
            ,Column_ID = "Column_ID"::text
            ,FromTable = "FromTable"
            ,Operation = "Operation"
            ,Amount = "Amount"
            ,CriteriaType_1 = CASE WHEN "CriteriaType_1" <> '' THEN ('WHERE 
' || "CriteriaType_1") ELSE '' END
            ,Function_1 = CASE WHEN "Function_1" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Function_1" END
            ,Criteria_1 = CASE WHEN "Criteria_1" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Criteria_1" END
            ,CriteriaType_2 = CASE WHEN "CriteriaType_2" <> '' THEN ' AND ' 
|| "CriteriaType_2" ELSE '' END
            ,Function_2 = CASE WHEN "Function_2" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Function_2" END
            ,Criteria_2 = CASE WHEN "Criteria_2" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Criteria_2" END
            ,CriteriaType_3 = CASE WHEN "CriteriaType_3" <> '' THEN ' AND ' 
|| "CriteriaType_3" ELSE '' END
            ,Function_3 = CASE WHEN "Function_3" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Function_3" END
            ,Criteria_3 = CASE WHEN "Criteria_3" is null THEN 'Empty' ELSE 
"Criteria_3" END
     FROM public.logic_table_rcd WHERE "LogicID" = INC;
     
sql:= 'INSERT INTO public.logic_result_rcd SELECT ' || INC::text || ', 1, ' 
|| EntityID::text || ', ' || DateKey::text || ', ' || 'RCD' || ', ' || 
SheetName::text || ', ' || Row_ID::text || ', ' || Column_ID::text || ', ' 
|| Operation || '(' || Amount || ')' || ' FROM ' || FromTable
    || CriteriaType_1 || ' ' || Function_1 || ' ' || Criteria_1
    || CriteriaType_2 || ' ' || Function_2 || ' ' || Criteria_2
    || CriteriaType_3 || ' ' || Function_3 || ' ' || Criteria_3;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
END;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor_logic;
END;
END;

$body$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: select into... or perform select (discarding result)

Comment: thank you. but i'm new to postgres and don't know how to write select into  ... or perform select (discarding result). can you write part of code that is incorrect???

Comment: error happens at ```SELECT  LogicID = "LogicID"  ,SheetName = "SheetNa.....WHERE "LogicID" = INC;``` - you ether should "put" result somewhere or discard it. from your code I assume you at all wanted to assign thiat sql as text value to variable sql. but I cant tell it -because your post lacks comments

Comment: select into does not work with already existing table? am i right?

Comment: in this part of code

Comment: it does, and insert into can be into variables, not table

Comment: yes, i just want to assinng values to variables

Comment: I provided a working example of how you do it - please read

Comment: if i use perform, null values are assigned to variables. and i can't use then then. how should i assign values to variables to use then afterwards in dynamic query???

Comment: please look below - I provide example of assigning a query text to a variable and then run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign value with `VAR_NAME := '';` construct, here is an example:

```
t=# create function f(_i int) returns table (a int) as $$
declare sql text;
begin
 sql := format('select %s',_i);
 return query execute sql;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select * From f(3);
 a
---
 3
(1 row)
```

Comment: thank you. i've successfully assigned values to variables.now, problem is "ERROR:  cannot open INSERT query as cursor".

Comment: post the code, error and question as a new post please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423638/postgresql-cannot-open-insert-query-as-cursor